# How i can get all products except duplicates?

Tags: python, django

I have 2 models:

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    ...
    products = models.ManyToManyField('self', related_name='products')  

class OrderProduct(models.Model):
    """Products for Order that a user added in his cart."""
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='order_products')
```

I need to get all OrderProduct.product.products but without duplicates

I tried to solve it like:

```py
suggestions = [product.product.products.all().distinct() for product in order_products]
```

But I got

```py
[<QuerySet [<Product: Apple iMac Retina 5K>, <Product: iMac Pro>, <Product: Apple MacBook Air 2020>]>, <QuerySet [<Product: Apple iMac Retina 5K>, <Product: iMac Pro>]>]
```

That's a list of querysets, not products list

I want to get result like

```py
QuerySet [Product: Apple iMac Retina 5k>, Product: iMac Pro>, Product: Apple MacBook Air 2020>]
```

(so it looks like the result in my previous code, but in a 1 queryset and without duplicates (distinct))

Comment: What is `order_products`? A list, a `QuerySet`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain the products with:

```
Product.objects.filter(
    products__products__in=order_products.values('product')
).distinct()
```

This works because a many-to-many field to itself is by default [**`symmetrical`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.symmetrical), so if product *A* is related to product *B*, then product *B* is related to product *A*.

Note that this will also make *one* query, instead of the *N* queries in the given example.

Comment: Thanks, that's working, BTW you missed order_products.values('product') :)